# Solving expression containing the multiple NOTs

Tags: python

I want to run the program with multiple NOT in the statement but not able to do that.
Suppose I wrote the equation as NOT TRUE and pass it into the variables as `["NOT", "TRUE"]`, then I am able to get the right answer that is `["FALSE"]`.
Now when I am passing variables as `["NOT", "NOT", "TRUE"]` then I am getting the output is `["TRUE","TRUE"]` but it should be `["TRUE"]`.

What changes need to be done in the code below?

```
def implement_not(variable):
    pos_minus = variable.index('NOT')

    if (variable[pos_minus + 1] == 'TRUE'):
        variable[pos_minus + 1] = 'FALSE'
    else:
        variable[pos_minus + 1] = 'TRUE'
    del variable[pos_minus]
    return variable
```

Comment: The easy answer would be to realize that two NOTs cancel each other.  So, if NOT is followed by NOT, delete them both.  Ans `if` statements in Python don't need parentheses.

Comment: And of course, if you do get "NOT NOT", your response needs to be "who's there"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here - the first is that you need to search from the end, rather than the beginning, because in `NOT NOT TRUE`, the second one should be evaluated first. The second problem is that you shouldn't assume that everything that isn't `TRUE` is `FALSE`. This code fixes both problems.

```py
def implement_not(variable):
    pos_minus = len(variable) - variable[::-1].index('NOT') - 1
    
    if variable[pos_minus + 1] == 'TRUE':
        variable[pos_minus + 1] = 'FALSE'
        del variable[pos_minus]
    elif variable[pos_minus + 1] == 'FALSE':
        variable[pos_minus + 1] = 'TRUE'
        del variable[pos_minus]
    return variable
```

It's also probably good to note that this method mutates the list, so it's not really necessary to return it, because the caller already has a reference to it. You also might need to call it multiple times to handle all of the `NOT`s, so it might be useful to instead return a status code for whether it needs to be called again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this using a totally different approach:

```
>>> def implement_not(var: List) -> List[str]:
      s = ' '.join(var).replace('NOT NOT ', '')
...   return ['FALSE'] if 'NOT ' in s else [s] 
... 
>>> implement_not(['TRUE'])
['TRUE']
>>> implement_not(['NOT', 'TRUE'])
['FALSE']
>>> implement_not(['NOT', 'NOT', 'TRUE'])
['TRUE']
>>> implement_not(['NOT', 'NOT', 'NOT', 'TRUE'])
['FALSE']
>>> implement_not(['NOT', 'NOT', 'NOT', 'NOT', 'TRUE'])
['TRUE']
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a rare case where `eval()` can help you!

```py
>>> mapping = {
...     "TRUE":  "True",
...     "FALSE": "False",
...     "NOT":   "not",
... }
>>> eval(" ".join(mapping[k] for k in ["NOT", "NOT", "TRUE"]))
True
>>> eval(" ".join(mapping[k] for k in ["NOT", "NOT", "NOT", "TRUE"]))
False
```

This works by assembling a string of valid Python syntax from the possible words.

If you want the resulting word, you can simply provide that (all results will simplify to "TRUE" or "FALSE" or be invalid)

```
    return ["TRUE"] if my_test() else ["FALSE"]
```

---

This will raise `KeyError` for values not in the lookup table, which provides execution safety around using `exec()`

```py
>>> eval(" ".join(boolean_values[k] for k in ["TRUE", "SOMETHING_EVIL()"]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
KeyError: 'SOMETHING_EVIL()'
```

Invalid collections will also raise `SyntaxError`

```py
>>> eval(" ".join(boolean_values[k] for k in ["TRUE", "TRUE"]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    True True
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

---

If, as [**@Anthony Perot** suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66699953/4541045), your input is a string to begin with, you can assign the values to variables before `exec()`ing, and pass them via its `locals` argument

```py
true  = True
false = False
exec(original_string.lower(), locals=locals())
```

However, **BEWARE** this not **NOT SAFE** for untrusted inputs as it will run any valid Python with the same privileges as the process, meaning if there are untrusted inputs (ie. web clients), your system will eventually be compromised by evildoers